# How to upload photos from web form to Flickr?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how to upload photos to Flickr using python and Django?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

```
It can be accomplished using the Flickr API for python. There are two or three good implementations. 
Search for Python Flickr API. Thanks again!
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this: [flickr upload  api](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html)